# Is it possible to do a redirect on class based views

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

Is it possible to do a redirect on class based views. Like i have other contexts to return but if assuming I have blocked the user, i want to redirect to home page and make it such that they cannot view the detail page. Sorry! am new to class based views

```
class DetailBlogPostView(BlogPostMixin,DetailView):
    template_name = 'HomeFeed/detail_blog.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        if blog_post.author in self.request.user.blocked_users.all():
            return redirect('HomeFeed:main')
        else:
            return redirect('HomeFeed:main')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        blog_post=self.get_object()
        blog_post.save()
        context['blog_post'] = blog_post
        account = Account.objects.all()
        context['account'] = account
        #aka if blog post does belong to me
        if blog_post.author in self.request.user.blocked_users.all():
            return redirect('HomeFeed:main')
        else:
            if blog_post.author != self.request.user:
                    context["interest_pk"]=blog_post.interest_set.first().pk
               #if blog post belongs to me
            if blog_post.interest_set.exists():
                context["interest_pk"]=blog_post.interest_set.first().pk

        return context
```

Comment: Have tried [`UserPassesTestMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.UserPassesTestMixin) ?

Comment: @JPG thanks for input man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

If the user is blocked pass a message to the context and display it in a template, otherwise display the data:

```
class DetailBlogPostView(BlogPostMixin, DetailView):
    template_name = 'HomeFeed/detail_blog.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        user = User.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        if request.user in user.blocked_users.all():
            context['message'] = 'This user blocked you'
        else:
            context['user'] = user
            # add other context
        return context
```

**template.html**

```
{% if message %}
    {{ message }}
{% else %}
...
{% endif %}
```

**UPDATE**

Alternatively you can use `get_success_url()` method to redirect your users like this:

```
def get_success_url(self):
    user = User.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
    if request.user in user.blocked_users.all():
        return redirect('somewhere')
    else:
        return redirect('somewhere_else')
```

Comment: nope not working bro..getting this error `typeerror: context must be a dict rather than HttpResponseRedirect.
`

Comment: bro so there is no way to redirect right. This is a scenario where if you type the exact url link to my detail blog page, i want to redirect them back to home page @SLDem i have edited the code too

Comment: well JPG has commented a pretty good solution, you can try using `permission_classes` to redirect your blocked users but you will have to write your own Permission, it shouldn't be that had though

Comment: okay trust you :) I'll go check out JPG's recommendation!

Comment: Bro, check out my update, I think it might work.

Comment: Hi bro, I have updated my code. Not sure if I understood your code correctly. There were no errors but I wasn't redirected @SLDem

Comment: ops disregard that, that code is actually for `POST` requests